# Is it possible to use WordPress functions in a page template?

Tags: login, templates

When a user enters a page I want to check if he is logged in.
How can it be done in the page's template?
Or is it possible only in functions.php or a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (is_user_logged_in())
{
    echo 'You are logged in. Yay!';
}
```

Codex: [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Comment: Thanks, Geert. Does this mean I can use all WP API elements (functions, hooks, filters) in a template?

Comment: And yes, you can use all the same functions, hooks and filters available in a normal page template

Comment: @Ash: Template files are just like all PHP files, so yes, you have access to the complete WordPress API there.

Comment: Generally speaking, template tags, conditional tags, and public functions are all perfectly valid for use within template files. I would suggest, though, that hooks (and their callbacks), should be used *only* in `functions.php`.